# Including a link for manifest.json file crashes Lighthouse audit in chrome

Tags: progressive-web-apps, manifest

The lighthouse audit hangs while running an audit.
I tried removing the manifest.json link and it runs the audit fine.

here's the manifest.json file

```
{
  "name": "Our School",
  "short_name": "ourschool",
  "start_url": "/index.html",
  "display": "standalone",
  "background_color": "#fff",
  "theme_color": "#fff",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "/img/icon-72x72.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "72x72"
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

here's how I linked the file in HTML.

```
<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the "Clear storage" checkbox is unchecked, you can find this in the in lighthouse settings.
[image: Clear storage]