# Why does my PWA works on my phone but not on others?

Tags: progressive-web-apps

Good day, I'm currently working on PWAs (Progressive Web Apps), and I wanted to make a try:

Here is my app script:

```
if( 'serviceWorker' in navigator ) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register( '/service-worker.js' )
    .then( ( reg ) => logServe( 'service worker registred', reg ) )
    .catch( ( err ) => logServe( 'service worker not registred', err ) );
}
```

Here is my manifest:

```
{
    "name": "WebApp",
    "short_name": "PWA",
    "description": "Progressive Web App",
    "start_url": "/",
    "icons": [
        {
            "src": "icon/icon-512.png",
            "sizes": "512x512",
            "type": "image/png",
            "purpose": "any"
        },
        {
            "src": "icon/icon-256.png",
            "sizes": "256x256",
            "type": "image/png",
            "purpose": "any"
        },
        {
            "src": "icon/icon-192.png",
            "sizes": "192x192",
            "type": "image/png",
            "purpose": "any"
        },
        {
            "src": "icon/icon-96.png",
            "sizes": "96x96",
            "type": "image/png",
            "purpose": "any"
        }
    ],
    "theme_color": "#000000",
    "background_color": "#FFFFFF",
    "display": "standalone",
    "orientation": "portrait"
}
```

And here is my service worker:

```
self.addEventListener( 'install', evt => {
    logServe( 'service worker has been installed' );
} );

self.addEventListener( 'activate', evt => {
    logServe( 'service worker has been activated' );
} );

self.addEventListener( 'fetch', evt => {
    logServe( 'fetch event', evt );
} );
```

To test it, I tried:

- On my computer (with edge/chrome) -> I can see the default install button in the address bar, and allow me to install it
- On my samsung phone through `ngrok` and on chrome -> It shows the button* I've set up to install the app and allow me to install it

Here is the script for my custom installation button*:

```
let deferredPrompt;
const addBtn = document.getElementsByTagName( 'a' )[0];
addBtn.style.display = 'none';

window.addEventListener( 'beforeinstallprompt', ( e ) => {
    // Prevent Chrome 67 and earlier from automatically showing the prompt
    e.preventDefault();
    
    // Stash the event so it can be triggered later.
    deferredPrompt = e;
    
    // Update UI to notify the user they can add to home screen
    addBtn.style.display = 'block';
    
    addBtn.addEventListener( 'click', ( e ) => {
        // hide our user interface that shows our A2HS button
        addBtn.style.display = 'none';
        
        // Show the prompt
        deferredPrompt.prompt();
        
        // Wait for the user to respond to the prompt
        deferredPrompt.userChoice.then( ( choiceResult ) => {
            if( choiceResult.outcome === 'accepted' ) {
                console.log( 'User accepted the A2HS prompt' );
            } else {
                console.log( 'User dismissed the A2HS prompt' );
            }
            
            deferredPrompt = null;
         } );
    } );
} );
```

But as soon as I try on another device, it fails, I see the "service worker registered", but that's it.

So I checked on a PWA framework/validator (PWA Builder), and this validator told me I got all that is required to publish my PWA.

Any idea from where it's coming from?

**EDIT**

After sorting out my Lighthouse issue, I performed few tests and tried correcting some pointS, but I still have 2 issues I cannot solve:

- a HTTP redirecting issue, I tried with the HTML tag `<link rel="canonical" href="my https domain url"/>` or with the following HTACCESS:

  ```
    #RewriteEngine on
    #ReWriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
    #RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NC,R,L]
  ```

but I still have this issue (if possible, I would like to avoid making server set up to solve this.

- a maskable issue on Chrome (even if I added maskables icons)

Here is my new icons definition:

```
    {
        "src": "icon/any/x512.png",
        "sizes": "512x512",
        "type": "image/png",
        "purpose": "any"
    },
    {
        "src": "icon/any/x384.png",
        "sizes": "384x384",
        "type": "image/png",
        "purpose": "any"
    },
    {
        "src": "icon/any/x192.png",
        "sizes": "192x192",
        "type": "image/png",
        "purpose": "any"
    },
    {
        "src": "icon/any/x128.png",
        "sizes": "128x128",
        "type": "image/png",
        "purpose": "any"
    },
    {
        "src": "icon/any/x96.png",
        "sizes": "96x96",
        "type": "image/png",
        "purpose": "any"
    },
    {
        "src": "icon/any/x72.png",
        "sizes": "72x72",
        "type": "image/png",
        "purpose": "any"
    },
    {
        "src": "icon/any/x48.png",
        "sizes": "48x48",
        "type": "image/png",
        "purpose": "any"
    },
    {
        "src": "icon/maskable/x512.png",
        "sizes": "512x512",
        "type": "image/png",
        "purpose": "maskable"
    },
    {
        "src": "icon/maskable/x384.png",
        "sizes": "384x384",
        "type": "image/png",
        "purpose": "maskable"
    },
    {
        "src": "icon/maskable/x192.png",
        "sizes": "192x192",
        "type": "image/png",
        "purpose": "maskable"
    },
    {
        "src": "icon/maskable/x128.png",
        "sizes": "128x128",
        "type": "image/png",
        "purpose": "maskable"
    },
    {
        "src": "icon/maskable/x96.png",
        "sizes": "96x96",
        "type": "image/png",
        "purpose": "maskable"
    },
    {
        "src": "icon/maskable/x72.png",
        "sizes": "72x72",
        "type": "image/png",
        "purpose": "maskable"
    },
    {
        "src": "icon/maskable/x48.png",
        "sizes": "48x48",
        "type": "image/png",
        "purpose": "maskable"
    }
```

Here is what happen on Edge - Chrome when doing a Lighthouse test (Edge vs Chrome)

[lighthouse edge and chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXOPc.png)

Comment: Which other device are you trying? Also have you tried to run the Chrome lighthouse test?

Comment: @GuillermoRomero I tried on (chrome, samsung internet, safari) and on different phones (iphone 10, s9+, galaxy s20 fe, Redmi note 9 Pro) as well as on windows 10 (edge, chrome, opera)s. Actually, I tried performing a lighthouse test from my opera, edge and chrome browers, the only one who reached the end of the test and did not stuck before was edge, and it didn't show any special errors (and I cannot make Lighthouse test anymore on it, it stucks as wel nowl...)

Comment: You can follow this step to solve the the issue with lighthouse: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70418725/8716572 Also there is something to consider, unfortunately it's not possible to have this functionality in iOS, for iOS you still need to manually install the pwa

Comment: @GuillermoRomero really appreciated your link for the lighthouse issue, I tried lot of thing before but I never sorted it out till now, I edited my post regarding my PWA issues.

Comment: Are you using HTTPS at the moment?